# How linux command name are unique?

Tags: package-management

There are a lot of Linux commands available, either recently or from the early age of UNIX. Some are well known, like `cat`, `top`, `sudo`, etc... and some less.

How people manage to keep command name unique? If someone create a `foo` command, how does he know that `foo` is not already used by someone else and available via `apt`, `github`, `snap` or whatever else?

Comment: The don't - see for example [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename). However there are ways to manage conflicts using `update-alternatives` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the command in the terminal to check if the package that installs that command is available from the default Ubuntu repositories.

This example shows that command 'foo' is not found, and suggests some apt and snap packages that provide commands that have names similar to foo. Note the `$` command prompt which indicates that the command is supposed to be run as normal user, not root.

```
$ foo

Command 'foo' not found, did you mean:

  command 'roo' from snap roo (2.0.3)
  command 'fox' from deb objcryst-fox
  command 'woo' from deb python-woo
  command 'fog' from deb ruby-fog
  command 'goo' from deb goo
  command 'fgo' from deb fgo
  command 'fop' from deb fop
  command 'fio' from deb fio

See 'snap info ' for additional versions.
```

This example shows that a package that provides the command 'bar' is available from the default Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with `sudo apt install bar` . Note the `$` command prompt which indicates that the command is supposed to be run as normal user, not root.

```
$ bar

Command 'bar' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install bar
```

Comment: I would not run programs that I don't know if they exist and if they exist don't know what they do. I'd rather go with searching on the web, e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com or https://debian.org/distrib/packages or https://snapcraft.io/store or use `apt show foo`